# Android DHCP mechanism of portable wifi hotspot

Tags: java, android, android-networking

When I turn on Android Wifi Hotspot, Others join into my network and get Ip addresses.

1. How's the mechanism of distributing IP addresses between my phone
   and clients ?
2. So is there any methods(Java, Android) or any files in the Phone
   system that I need to config to change My Ipaddress(As a Server
   Ipadress) and DHCP IP range ??

Comment: Anyone has any ideas ???